# android timer loop in a thread to be accessible multiple activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I’m working on a small project that sends and receives data via Bluetooth between an Android Tablet and an Arduino board.

My application has two separate Activities (Configure and Operate) that needs to have access to the Bluetooth send and receive messages.

Currently I have a Message Handler with Runnable Delay Loop in the Operate Activity, but I’m running into issues with when trying to send and receive date from the Configure Activity.

My thought is to put the Message Handler with Runnable Delay Loop in a background thread and then send messages to that thread from the Activities (Configure and Operate). That thread send out the messages the two Activities and handle the response from the Arduino board.

What is a good way to go about this?

Comment: Have the Bluetooth communications be managed by a singleton (e.g., one set up via Dagger/Hilt). That singleton can have background threads for timing as needed (e.g., `ScheduledExecutorService`, RxJava). Have that singleton expose a reactive API (e.g., RxJava) that your UI layer consumes (e.g., via a Jetpack `ViewModel`), so it can react to incoming messages as needed. That singleton can also expose an API for sending messages that the UI layer can invoke when needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the reply, but I’m new to Android coding. So I apologize for having to ask for more clarification. What is a Dagger/Hilt and Jetpak?

Comment: "I’m new to Android coding" -- what book did you read, or what course did you take, to learn Android app development? If you did neither of those things... you might consider trying that. If it helps, I have [several free books on Android app development](https://commonsware.com/catalog). I cover a number of Jetpack libraries, including `ViewModel`. I also cover dependency inversion frameworks, of which [Dagger/Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection) is one, though I focus on a simpler Kotlin option called Koin.

Comment: @CommonsWare
Besides all the normal online examples and a Java book from a one of my undergrad classes I have taken one on-line course from www.udemy. The "Android App Development Master Course with Java | Android" course a great refresher of Java and a OK introduction to Android coding.

Comment: I cannot speak to the content of that Udemy course, but most of their marketing materials have not been updated in years, based on the terminology that they used. And, if they did not reference "Jetpack", then the content itself has not been updated in years, either. For example, the "Architecture Components" were replaced by Jetpack in May 2018.